# GStreamer connection to VLC using GstRTSP library

Tags: gstreamer, vlc, rtsp, rtp, sdp

I am trying to write a C application to connect with VLC RTSP (via RTP) stream and save frames as images.
I use the GStreamer RTSP library: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/gst-plugins-base-rtsp-1.0/index.html?gi-language=c

I have written some simple code presented below, but the app wait for the message from the VLC. I am not sure if it is a good way to connect but I am in stuck now. Maybe I should send something first to VLC but I do not know what and how to do this. Could anyone help or point some resources/examples how to use GStreamer RTSP?

```
#include <gstreamer-1.0/gst/rtsp/rtsp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    GstRTSPUrl *gstUrl = NULL;
    const char* url = "rtsp://10.30.1.163:8554/test.sdp";
    if(gst_rtsp_url_parse(url, &gstUrl) == GST_RTSP_OK) {
        printf("URL PARSE");
        GstRTSPConnection *gstRTSPConnection = NULL;
        if(gst_rtsp_connection_create(gstUrl, &gstRTSPConnection) == GST_RTSP_OK) {
            printf("Connection created\n");
            GstRTSPMessage *message = NULL;
            gst_rtsp_message_new(&message);
            GstRTSPResult result = gst_rtsp_connection_connect_with_response(gstRTSPConnection, NULL, message);
            if(result == GST_RTSP_ETIMEOUT){
                printf("Timeout\n");
            } else if(result == GST_RTSP_OK) {
                printf("Connected\n");
                printf("%s\n", gst_rtsp_connection_get_ip(gstRTSPConnection));
                printf("Is tunelled: %d\n", gst_rtsp_connection_is_tunneled(gstRTSPConnection));
                gst_rtsp_connection_receive(gstRTSPConnection, message, NULL);
            }
        }
    }    

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I will handle this. The issue was I need to first send some message to the server according to RTSP protocol. The solution below (with some dump messages):

```
#include <gstreamer-1.0/gst/rtsp/rtsp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() 
{
    GstRTSPUrl *gstUrl = NULL;
    const char* url = "rtsp://10.30.1.163:8554";
    if(gst_rtsp_url_parse(url, &gstUrl) == GST_RTSP_OK) {
        printf("URL PARSE");
        GstRTSPConnection *gstRTSPConnection = NULL;
        if(gst_rtsp_connection_create(gstUrl, &gstRTSPConnection) == GST_RTSP_OK) {
            printf("Connection created\n");
            GstRTSPMessage *message = NULL;
            gst_rtsp_message_new(&message);
            GstRTSPResult result = gst_rtsp_connection_connect_with_response(gstRTSPConnection, NULL, message);
            if(result == GST_RTSP_ETIMEOUT){
                printf("Timeout\n");
            } else if(result == GST_RTSP_OK) {
                printf("Connected\n");
                printf("%s\n", gst_rtsp_connection_get_ip(gstRTSPConnection));
                printf("Is tunelled: %d\n", gst_rtsp_connection_is_tunneled(gstRTSPConnection));

                gst_rtsp_message_new(&message);
                gst_rtsp_message_init_request(message, GST_RTSP_DESCRIBE, "rtsp://10.30.1.163:8554/test.sdp");
                gst_rtsp_message_add_header(message, GST_RTSP_HDR_CSEQ, "1");
                printf("Message Type %d", gst_rtsp_message_get_type(message));


                gst_rtsp_message_dump(message);

                if(gst_rtsp_connection_send(gstRTSPConnection, message, NULL) == GST_RTSP_OK){
                    printf("Message sent");
                }else {
                    printf("Message not sent");
                }
                gst_rtsp_connection_receive(gstRTSPConnection, message, NULL);

                gst_rtsp_message_dump(message);
            }
        }
    }    

    return 0;
}
```